# Groovy's xml find seems to fail on empty elements

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm running in to something using groovy's xml find method.  I have to say, up front, this is my first groovy script every, and I don't deal a whole lot with XML.

Here's a summary of the problem, a more concrete example follows below:

I am trying to write some smoke tests for one of our systems.  As part of that, i have to compare XML documents (expected vs actual).  The ordering of elements within the XML is non-deterministic, and the software that is responsible for that is something I can't touch, so I have to work around it.  Not a big deal, I want to pull the child nodes off the XML and compare them against each other.  Part of the XML I want to look at has a lot of empty elements, which I want to consider separately.  For some reason, when I use the groovy XML find method, it's grouping all the empty elements together as one result instead of (in this case) 7 separate results.  And since the ordering of those elements is variable, my tests are crashing.  It is no good to me.

Example!

So.  Here's a snippet from the xml document.  This is the particular part that's giving me trouble (I had to do some find-replace to anonymize it):

```
<d_sorted>
              <comparator class="comparatorClass"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[7]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[2]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[4]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[5]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[6]/someTag"/>
   </d_sorted>
```

You're going to have to trust me here, the XML document as a whole is well formed, nothing weird about it, but it's too big to just copy paste in here and it's got some company stuff in it.

Here's the groovy call I'm using to search it:

```
expectedEntries = myXMLDocument.topLevelTag.'**'.findAll{it.someTag})
```

Here's what comes back from that:

```
 <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[7]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[2]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[4]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[5]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[6]/someTag"/>
```

as one element.  Which doesn't do me a whole lot of good, since that's what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  It looks like it's choking on the empty elements but I don't understand why that would be.

Comment: It didn't return one element.  findAll returned a collection of elements - a list of each someTag element.  do expectedEntries.each{println it} and you'll see each element in the list.

Comment: GAAAH.  Yes. I'll add some clarification to the post, but for whatever reason, groovy was returning other elements with someTag as nodes, but this one was being returned as a list of nodes.  But you're absolutely right, it was returning the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which parser you're using, but the [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) is pretty neat!

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
    '''<d_sorted>
              <comparator class="comparatorClass"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[7]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[2]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[4]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[5]/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry/someTag"/>
              <someTag reference="../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[6]/someTag"/>
   </d_sorted>''' )

assert rootNode.someTag*.@reference == [
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[7]/someTag', 
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[2]/someTag',
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag', 
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[4]/someTag', 
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[5]/someTag', 
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry/someTag', 
    '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[6]/someTag'
]

// toString() is blank because there's no child text
assert rootNode.someTag[0] == ''

assert rootNode.someTag*.@reference.findAll { 
    it.@reference == '../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag'
} == ['../../d_deltaMap/d_rep/entry[3]/someTag']
```

As you can see, the `assert` statements show that the *someTag* elements are accessible.

Comment: Huh.  I was using XmlParser.  I'll try it with slurper and see what happens